# If Richtextbox1.contains(TextBox1.Text) - Error

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get Richtextbox1 to do the contain function but it's giving me an error: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Basically the statement should read: If RichTextBox1 contains the contents of TextBox1 Then ....

```
If RichTextBox1.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
```

Comment: You are using `System.Windows.Forms.Control.Contains` method, which (according to the documentation) "Retrieves a value indicating whether the specified control is a child of the control".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add in the Text property.

```
If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains(TextBox1.Text)
```

(untested air code)

Comment: Can you please take a look at this also, I tried everything and still nothing works. http://prntscr.com/5pdlxm

Comment: Because the line before you set it to nothing, this cant be a trick question is it?

Comment: I also tried it without the = Nothing line, still nothing.